# How to write a query for creating an stored proceedure in mysql

Tags: mysql

How to write a query for creating an stored procedure in mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [relevant MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html).

Answer (score 2):

A really simple way to get a jump on creating the stored procedure is to use something like the [MySQL Query Browser](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/query-browser/en/).  I use this tool all the time for writing stored procedures and functions.

With that tool, you do the following:

1. Right-click on the database from the Schemata tab that you want to create the proc/func in.
2. Choose "Create New Stored Procedure/Function" or type CTRL-P.
3. Enter the name of the procedure/function.
4. Click the **Create PROCEDURE** or **Create FUNCTION** button.

This will create a skeleton stored procedure or function with all the DELIMITER and DROP PROCEDURE/DROP FUNCTION lines written for you.  You can tweak them if you need to but I don't generally find the need to do that.

Then you can flesh out the proc/func and Click **Execute** and, assuming you don't have a syntax error, you've got a stored procedure.

The skeleton stored procedure it generates looks something like this:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `database-name`.`proc-name` $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `database-name`.`proc-name` ()
BEGIN

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Hope that helps.

Note:  The button text and prompts might vary just slightly between versions of the tool, but otherwise it works the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE prc_filler (cnt INT)
BEGIN
       SELECT  name
       FROM    data;
END
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I have used the following code

DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `prc_filler`(cnt INT)
BEGIN
        SELECT name from Data
END
$$

DELIMITER ;

But i gets the error

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4

do you have any idea

Answer (score 0):

a few simple examples:

```
 delimiter ;

 drop procedure if exists get_user;

 delimiter #

 create procedure get_user
 (
   in p_user_id int unsigned
 )
 begin
   select * from users where user_id = p_user_id;
 end #

 delimiter ;


 drop procedure if exists list_users;

 delimiter #

 create procedure list_users()
 begin
   select * from users order by username;
 end #

 delimiter ;
```